# Equivalence of Cohomology groups

Tags: algebraic-topology

Suppose $n=i+j,$ with $n, i,j$ positive integers. Let $I^k$ denote the $k$-dimensional unit square.

It is claimed (in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology text) that $H^i(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \mathbb{R}^j)$ is isomorphic to $H^i(I^i, \partial I^i).$  Why is this true?  My guess is that I need to use excision, but I don't see how.

Comment: Do you mean $H^i$?

Comment: Do you, by any chance mean "isomorphic to $H_{i-1}(I^{i}, \partial I^{i})$" instead of $H_{i}(\ldots)$ ?

Comment: @Michael Weiss: Yes, I do! (I'll edit them). Apologies.

Comment: Could you give a page number for where this occurs?

Comment: @Michael Weiss. See here the comment on the bottom of page 221: http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATch3.pdf (The online chapter has be rewritten from the paper version, so the pages will not match on the paper copy).

Answer (score 1):

There is a (linear) deformation retract of pairs $(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \mathbb{R}^j) \to (\mathbb{R}^i, \mathbb{R}^i \setminus 0)$. Now use excision to change to $(I^i, I^i \setminus 0)$. Finally the inclusion $(I^i, \partial I^i) \to (I^i, I^i \setminus 0)$ is a homotopy equivalence $\partial I^i \to I^i \setminus 0$, so induces isomphisms on relative (co)homology by the five lemma.